# Describing a Traumatic Silence

Tags: creative-writing, language

I am finishing a short story by describing how the silence of a deceased character is more unnerving than that character's cries before he died.

Is there a simile to describe a traumatic or gut-wrenching scene?

Comment: If you can think of a more specific question to ask that would help, please feel free to use the [edit] function to change this and well consider reopening.

Comment: @Neil (or others), do you think that with some revision this should be transplanted to EL&U?

Comment: @KaiMaxfield Maybe? It's worth trying, certainly.

Comment: @KaiMaxfield I'm not a mode there or even a frequent user, so I'd ask in their chat room. (You have sufficient rep there.) But I'd emphasize the part of the question asking for a term over the part that talks about writing.

Comment: @Standback How is this off-topic for Writers? ELU isn't really into writing advice.

Comment: Ronikos, 'gut-wrenching' is almost a dead metaphor for it, have you considered that?

Comment: @Mitch it was a consideration, yes, however I was looking for more creative suggestions to end the story on a more blunt note. I appreciate you seeing the merit in the question, thank you

Comment: @Mitch: Not off-topic because it isn't a writing question; off-topic because questions of the form `"what's a phrase to describe X"` or `"what's a simile for Y"` or `"I have written Z, help me rephrase it"` don't work as Q&A questions. For one thing, there's no "right" answer; you could have dozens of perfectly fine phrasings or rewrites. No less important, such questions flood the site (since they are very easy and natural to ask) but they have no value to anybody but the original poster.

Comment: I've written upon this in greater length on Meta, particularly this post: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/a/537/1046

Comment: @standback OK re closing reasoning. ELU has the same policy but I thought writers.se might allow such things.

Comment: @Mitch: That's an understandable thought to have :) Personally, and to my sorrow, I've found there are a lot of types of question that just don't work very well in the Stack Exchange format. It's not a flaw in the format, just kind of a necessary adjustment of expectations as to what the platform can and can't handle well. :)

Comment: Here is not the best place for a discussion on this but here goes anyway: the tech is called 'Q&A' and recommended to be 'one generic question expecting a clear objective answer (but allowing/encouraging different such 'answers'). But this tech can't enforce that so it also allows multiple local/narrow/personal subjective non-definitive answers, like Yahoo Answers (where anything goes). I'm leaning towards not trying to enforce.

Comment: In the EL&U chat, it became clear that migration wasn't an option unless major revision occurred. The OP thought this was more on-topic here than there anyway, and suggested sticking with what you pretty well already have, like, _The silence of the deceased was more unnerving than his cries before he died._

Comment: @Mitch: I'd be happy to discuss further on Meta or in chat :)

Answer (score 1):

Silence itself can be unnerving.
A ghostly slice or emptiness can be eerie. Or perhaps the calm after a tornado surrounded by the visual display of destruction.

Answer (score 1):

You could mention that it's like a beating heart being ripped from someone's chest.  One second beating, the next silent and still.

There's something conclusive about dead silence.  When a dying person cries, there's still hope for survival but in the silence that follows death, it's a hopeless black void.

The silence symbolizes the shift from life to death.

You could describe it as "jarring".  Like the shock of a bucket of ice water being poured over your head.  I think "unnerving" fits pretty well too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this "[The silence of the lambs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/)". While recent, this simile has wormed it's way into many heads.

Reference:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting in blank lines and/or many spaces between words to represent the silence. That makes the reader read “silence” and experience it along with the character. It is a fairly common poetry technique but is also used in prose.

Example:

```
he breathed                     and breathed          and        then







nothing
```